# django-channels: Not Found: /ws/

Tags: django, websocket, channel, htmx

Hi I have typical django app for real-time notifications using websockets

Have 2 apps "core" and "notification"

I need to show notification on notification page when Review is created. I added channels core and notification to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
"channels",
"core",
"notification",
]
```

Added asgi configuration

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "reviewproject.asgi.application"
```

Configured channel layers

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
},
```

}

Here is asgi.py

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import notification.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "reviewproject.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                notification.routing.websocket_urlpattern
            )
        )
    }
)
```

I also have routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpattern = [
    re_path(r'ws/notification/$', consumers.NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

consumer.py

```
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.group_name = "notification"

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def send_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))
```

And sending notification when Review is created

```
class ProductView(View):
    def send_notification(self, message):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("notification", {"type": "send_message", "message": message})

    def get(self, request, pk):
        reviews = ReviewModel.objects.filter(product=pk)
        product = get_object_or_404(ProductModel, pk=pk)
        context = {
            "reviews": reviews,
            "product": product
        }

        return render(request, "product.html", context)

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        product = get_object_or_404(ProductModel, pk=pk)
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        rating = request.POST.get("rating")
        review = request.POST.get("review")

        new_review = ReviewModel.objects.create(
            product=product,
            name=name,
            rating=rating,
            review=review
        )
        new_review.save()

        message = {
            "product_name": product.product_name,
            "rating": rating,
            "review": review
        }
        self.send_notification(message)

        return HttpResponse("Thank you!! Your review is submitted successfully")
```

Also i have view to render notification page

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View


class NotificationView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "notification/index.html")
```

Here my html page to show notifications

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Feedback Collection System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.3"></script>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <p class="navbar-brand" hx-get="{% url 'dashboard-view' %}" hx-target=".body" hx-push-url="{% url 'dashboard-view' %}">Feedback Collection System</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h2>Notifications</h2>
        </div>
        <ul id="notification-list">
        </ul>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.3"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/notification/');

            socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                // Display the notification dynamically on the page
                // For example, you could show it in a toast, modal, or notification bar
                alert(data.message);
            };
        </script>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i have errors at traceback when i try to render notification page

```
Not Found: /ws/notification/
[01/Aug/2023 16:39:46] "GET /ws/notification/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2606
```

Comment: Did you find the issue to your problem? I am running into the same issue. I am not running as runserver but using daphne itself.

Answer (score 0):

i has same issue i resolved it by just using daphne just follow docs for installation and use daphne. i will work fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).